# How to create a drop down field to categorize content when creating new pages?

Tags: 7, entities, routes, nodes

I want to have a drop down field available so that when a content author (user) creates a new page, they can select which section of the website this new content should get placed.

For example, my top navigation may be **About Us > Services > Products**. A user creates a new page that should go on in the Products section. When they go to add the new page, there should be a drop down field that shows **About Us, Services, Products**. The user would select **Products** and when they save the page, that page will automatically get placed in the **Products** section of the website.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: a proper answer is dictated by how you are creating those sections, and what you want people to see when they go to those pages

Answer (score 2):

The drop-down can be created as a Taxonomy.

The section pages can all be one View with a Contextual Filter for each taxonomy term.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module for this. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> Features
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

By creating an hierarchical taxonomy, it should be straight forward for your content editors to use this feature. That would take care of the "dropdown" field you're looking for already.

Next you'd have to think of how to implement what you consider "section" of the website, how would you technically implement that? Could it be something like "can be accessed by a user who has access to role ABC?". I'm thinking of a few possible techniques for that, based on the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, possible with integrations from a few other modules also, such as:

- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access).

So please edit your question to better explain what you mean by "section". After you do, I can update my answer accordingly.